# Delete/modify a shortcut by targetpath with C#

Tags: c#, shortcut

We have users that rename the shortcut file on their desktop to our application. What is the best way to delete/modify the shortcut based on targetpath if the icon changes for the application? In other words, I'm having a hard time locating the file name because it keeps getting changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class:

> Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when
>   a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

Infact you can exploit `FileSystemWatcher.Changed`, `FileSystemWatcher.Created`, `FileSystemWatcher.Renamed` , `FileSystemWatcher.Deleted` events to keep control on your file.

Here is an example by MSDN:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = "mypath";
    /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
       the renaming of files or directories. */
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
       | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    // Only watch text files.
    watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

    // Add event handlers.
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

    // Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    // Wait for the user to quit the program.
    Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
    while(Console.Read()!='q');
}

// Define the event handlers.
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
   Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}

private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
    Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
}
```

Comment: Will this handle the name change if the app is not launched?

Comment: Yes, but obviously you should launch the application that handle the file.

Answer (score 1):

It's a nice question and I surprised that nobody answered it correctly in 10 years.

The code below iterate through all links in given folder and finds one with `TargetPath` pointing to the currently executing WinForms app.

Add COM reference to your project to `Windows Script Host Object Model`.

```
    using IWshRuntimeLibrary;

    private static void DeleteShortcuts(string path)
    {
        // Example for path: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);

        foreach (var fileName in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.lnk"))
        {
            WshShell shell = new WshShell();
            IWshShortcut link = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(fileName);
            if (link.TargetPath == Application.ExecutablePath)
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

*Note:* `Application.ExecutablePath` works for WinForms to get the current exe path, for Console app you should use `Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0])`. Refer to documentation for other types of projects.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming a shortcut does not modify the target path, however, the best way I know to work with shortcuts in c# is with the [`IwshRuntimeLibrary`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3905/Creating-Shell-Links-Shortcuts-in-NET-Programs-Usi).

Answer (score -1):

To delete a file please use [System.IO.File.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) method

To modify the file you can use [System.IO.File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext) method

> Update after comments from below :
>
> Please use the ShellClass to create or modify shortcuts Also you will
>   need to get the special directory from desktop using
>   Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory
>
> A very good example showing step by step can be found here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146757/Add-Remove-Startup-Folder-Shortcut-to-Your-App

Comment: Do you understand what the OP is asking?

Comment: @RobertHarvey & user766595 I do exactly know what he means but the catch here is OP is talking about the file not modifying the file with C# code